# How to use a method from grand Parent component to child component using props in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```js
const GrandParent = (props) => {
  const close = () => {
    console.log("Pressed");
  }
  return (<Parent func={() => close()} />)
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (<Child onPress={ /**call close function from GrandParent component*/} />)
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return (<Button onPress={() => props.onPress} />)
}
```

I was able to call `GrandParent`s component method from `Parent` component using the `props`, but I want to call it from the `Child` component and I can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this:

```js
const GrandParent = (props) => {
  const close = () => {
    console.log("Pressed")
  }
  return (<Parent func={() => close()} />)
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (<Child func={() => props.func()} />)
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return (<Button onPress={() => props.func()} />)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const GrandParent = (props) => {
  const close = () => {
    console.log("Pressed");
  }
 return (<Parent func={() => close()} />)
}

const Parent = (props) => {
  return (<Child onPress={()=> props.func()} fun1={()=> props.func()}/>)
}

const Child = (props) => {
  return (<Button onPress={()=> props.func1()} />)
}
```